# Internet explorer background disappears when insert page into div posting

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, background-image

this is a specific problem in IE.

i'm trying to insert an html into div, using the div like an iframe and it actually works
Something like this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#main_content').slideUp();
            $.post('main/main.html', function(data) {
                $('#main_content').html(data);
                $('#main_content').slideDown(800);
            });
        });
```

but the problem is when it's make this line $('#main_content').html(data); if I comment this line the background looks ok!

Any idea?

here goes the body

```
<body> <div id="allcontent" class="allcontent" align="center">    <div id="content" class="content_Style" style="position:relative; width:964px;">
    <div id="banner_div" class="banner_div_Style"  onclick="changeFrame('main/main.html'); movebackward ()"></div>

    <div id="menu_text_content">...</div>

    <div id="basemenu_content" class="basemenu_content_Style" align="center">
        <img alt="MENU" src="images/webbase-menu1.png" width="964" height="73" style="position: absolute;" />
    </div>
    <div id="calle_content" class="calle_contect_Style" align="center">
        <img alt="CONTENT" src="images/web-callev3.png" width="964" height="584" />
    </div>

    <div id="calle_botton_content" class="calle_botton_contect_Style" align="center">
        <img alt="CONTENT" src="images/web-callebajav3.png" width="964" height="496" style="filter:alpha(opacity=40)" />
        <div id="foot" class="foot_Style" >
            <img src="images/copyright.png" width="239" height="23" alt="Copyrights Mind Bright Productions, LLC" />        
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="main_content" class="main_content_Style">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using $.post not $.load ? Also I dont know whats inside your main.html but is there a background/css set there?

Comment: don't know what is $.load, but i use $.post to change de main content when click th menu;

Comment: there is a css body { 
 background: url(../images/webbase-.jpg) center top; 
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is youre getting the full html into the div. That is putting a second html structure into a html page, which certainly can cause unexpected results like with the background. Try just loading the body part of the page:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#main_content').slideUp();
     $('#main_content').load('main/main.html body');
     $('#main_content').slideDown(800);
    });
```

Comment: i think it could be because the main page have a css

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem doing what jtheman said but just with

```
$('#main_content').load('main/main.html');
```

And the in the main.html page, i take it out all the html, head and body definitions